# Which regular expression will let me match just the first and last letters?

Tags: c#, regex

Examples:

```
i General Biology i
i General Biology
General Biology i
```

I need to catch any phrase that begins with a single letter or number, ends with a letter or number, or both begins and ends with a single letter or number so that I can pre-parse the data to this:

```
General Biology
```

I've tried tons of examples on Rubular but can't seem to figure this one out. I've used literal match groups to get those characters but I don't want the match groups per se I literally just want the regex to only capture those two letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve this:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?i)^[a-z0-9]\s+|\s+[a-z0-9]$", "");
```

**Explanation**:

This removes a single letter/number at the beginning/end of the string followed or preceded by whitespace.

```
 (?i)        #  set flags for this block (case-insensitive)
 ^           #  the beginning of the string
 [a-z0-9]    #  any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
 \s+         #  whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
|            # OR
 \s+         #  whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
 [a-z0-9]    #  any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
 $           #  before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/uYNyWQ)